# Windows service setup: Error 1001

Tags: windows-services, installation

I am getting the following error when I try to install my service installer on my machine:

> Error 1001. The source was not found, but some or all event logs could be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security.
>
> Error 1001. An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete. --> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security.

I have created the window service as specified in the link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Please note: I dont have admin rights in this machine.

Comment: "This article also assumes that the user account that you use to install and to run this service has the permissions that you must have to install and to start services, and also has the permissions that you must have to access the event log." - does the user account you are using have these rights?

Comment: thanks..You are right. It was because of the permissions.